# Windows Phone 8 Geolocator returns fake location on emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I've tried to show my location in xaml windows phone 8 app. But always when I try to find my current location I get the fake microsoft location, even with the default maps app. For example, this code above always return same latitude and longitude:

```
Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
Geoposition position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
LatitudeValue.Text = position.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
LongitudeValue.Text = position.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8 emulator has a little toolbar on the top right.  The bottom button is a double chevron (like ">>") - if you click it it brings up "Additional Tools", and one of the tabs is "Location".  You can double-click on the map to set your location in the emulator, and you can also record and play back a travelled route.

Answer (score 4):

If I add a pushpin to the map and then call the

```
await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

It always returns the coordinates of Microsoft (47.643318, -122.141937), no matter which current location I chose.

It looks like a bug or am I missing something? Is there someone else experiencing this?

Comment: Seems that there's a work around. But it does not work with several position updates http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/c2cc57b1-ba1f-48fb-b285-d6cfbb8f393a

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! It works using the phone's native maps app.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the Microsoft HQ location bug, there is a work around.

If you set:

```
geoLocator = new Geolocator
                             {
                                 DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
                             };
```

It will show the location you setup in the emulator additional tools.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator always returns a fake location. As mentioned by gregstoll you can control which "fake" location it should be reporting. There's no way to get the true location using the built-in APIs.